# Passing Session Variables Through PHP Mail

Tags: php, forms, email, session, multipage

I'm having an issue passing $_SESSION variables through a multiple page form process using PHP mail. The emails are coming through fine, although they not displaying the variables. 
My goal is to have users fill out forms on multiple pages, and have the data emailed back to me.

Page 1

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
                  <form method="post" action="submitpage.php">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" value="car" checked />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/vehicle2.png">
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" value="suv" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/vehicle2.png">
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" value="van" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/vehicle2.png">
              </label>                                    
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" value="truck" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/vehicle2.png">
              </label>     
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" value="none" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/vehicle2.png">
              </label>                    
              </form>
```

Page 2

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['vehicle_type'] = $_POST['vehicle_type'];
?>
                  <form method="post" action="emailexample.php" id="submit-form">
              <input type="Email" name="email">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbtn">
              </form>
```

Page 3

```
<?php
session_start();

$to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test ';
$message = "Your Vehicle Type is: " . $_POST['vehicle_type'] ."\r\n";
$headers = 'From: email@example.com' . "\r\n" .


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: what session variables? page #3 doesn't use $_SESSION at all, just a $_POST variable...

Comment: I tried replacing $_POST with $_SESSION and still got a blank result emailed to me.

Comment: To debug, output the entire `$_SESSION` at each stage and see where session values stop persisting.

Comment: I've added print_r($_SESSION); to page 2, and it constantly comes up empty. It seems that the radio selection on page 1 never gets saved to a session variable when it's selected. Oh the frustration :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 1 you should put submit button something like this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

On page 3 you should change

```
$message = "Your Vehicle Type is: " . $_SESSION['vehicle_type'] ."\r\n";
```

and you're missing semicolon in $headers variable at the end. It should be

```
$headers = 'From: email@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: That is what I originally tried when the emails were coming up blank. It doesn't seem to work for me :/

Comment: Aha! Yes I see that I wasn't submitting the information to be saved into the session on page 1. It's working now! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm glad that It's working for you. Please accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

In page 3

use $_SESSION['vehicle_type'] instead of $_POST['vehicle_type']

Comment: As stated in the previous comment, this solution didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: make sure that $_POST['vehicle_type'] is not empty

Comment: It shouldn't be empty. Even if a selection isn't made, the defaulted "checked" radio value should still be coming through should it not?